# how to find which objects are selected:TRUE from 64 buttons labelled b1, b2 etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a project where there are 64 buttons, you have to click certain ones, then click 'done'.  If you clicked the right ones, you get some points, and those then need to disappear.
I have let the user keep track of which buttons are pressed by doing sender setSelected:TRUE.
The first bit is all working fine, but I'd like to be able to then hide the buttons that were selected when the user clicked 'done'.

My current thoughts are:
 - what I used in Actionscript to do the same thing was

> for (i=1;i++;i<65) {
>   if(getProperty ("b"+ i, _visible) == true) {do blah blah blah} }

I'm really really really hoping there is an obvious equivalent in objective C that does the same thing?

I definitely do not want to have to go through all 64 buttons and type if ([b1 isSelected == TRUE]etc...
I can't just use sender, as it may be several buttons that have previously been selected that I need to access.

EDIT - 
This is now the code that is called when user presses one of the 64 buttons.

```
        -(IBAction) pressed:(id)sender {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        if ([sender isSelected] ==FALSE) {  
            [sender setSelected:TRUE];  
        }
        else {
            [sender setSelected:FALSE];
        }
            if ([myArray containsObject:sender])
            {
                [myArray removeObject:sender];
            }
            else {
                [myArray addObject:sender];
            }
    }
```

This is called when they press the 'done' button.

> -(IBAction) checkTotal:(id)sender {

```
if (total == [(totaltxt.text) intValue]) {
    score += 1;
    scoretxt.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];
    for (UIButton *b in myArray)
    {
        [b setHidden:TRUE];
    }
    [myArray removeAllObjects];
    }

else {
    // some indication that they pressed the button but were wrong.
}
```

}

It unfortunately still won't hide the button.
It works if I change it to [n1 setHidden:TRUE] to hide the matching textbox above the button, but won't hide even a specific button -eg- [b1 setHidden:TRUE], let alone all the buttons in my array.
AAAAAAAARGH!!!!
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you describe your view hierarchy? Are the buttons the 'visible' element (ie containing some text or image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate on your view's subviews, and check whether the subview is a button:

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
    {
        // Do processing here
        // For instance:
        if ((UIButton *)view).isSelected)
            view.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to iterate through all the buttons then how about store a reference to your button in an array then just iterate through that array and clear it when the use clicks done?

```
    -(void)click:(id)sender
    {
       if([myArray containsObject:sender])
           [myArray removeObject:sender];
       else
       [myArray addObject:sender];

    } 

    -(void)doneClicked:(id)sender
    {
       for(UIButton *b in myArray)
    {
       [b setHidden:TRUE];
    }
    [myArray removeAllObjects]; //whateverr the method is i dont remember it off the top of my head

}
```

Comment: Will [myArray deleteObject:sender] work if they unselect the button?

Comment: it's not necessarily the last object that needs to be deleted

Comment: ok, tried it and it's not liking it... Weirdly, it will hide the textbox above button b1, using [n1 setHidden:TRUE], but won't hide the button using [b1 setHidden:TRUE] ! Is there something different I should do to hide buttons?

Comment: setHidden should work for buttons...not sure what you are doing but something is not right..

Comment: have posted new code - see edit.  Have also tried swapping hidden for .enabled, but that won't work either.

Comment: DUH!!! just checked, and I'd not yet set b1 as a referencing outlet as I was previously using the tab of the button to access it!

Comment: I can now hide specific buttons, but it still won't do it for all *b in myArray.

Comment: have tried - NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: but it won't let me do it - says my initialiser element is not a constant.  This is why I was hoping to avoid an array! I'm new to Objective C and my brain is letting me down!!

Comment: i mean why would you want to avoid arrays? even if you are new to objective-c...post the code you are using i can help you out

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I think I need a little more practice with arrays - not something I'm comfortable using yet! Makes it tricky to troubleshoot... You've been really helpful though :)

Comment: u should probably read up on some objective-c primer books...arrays are basic and are not difficult to use (if you know how to use arrays in any other programming enviroment)

Comment: yeah, I'm working on it - they're not something I've ever used in my other programming experience - I'm strictly an amateur...!

Answer (score 0):

Try [b setAlpha:0.0];

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag when creating the buttons and store the tag index in an array.

```
 -(IBAction) pressed:(id)sender {

}
```

by sender.tag

then finally run the loop hide all object 
and again run loop to unhide the object if it exists in array.